# If $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(N,p)$, then what is the distribution of $Y = N-X$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> Let $X\sim\text{Bin}(N,p).$ What is the distribution of $Y= N- X$?

Is it $Y\sim \text{Bin}(N,1-p)$?

Also, what is the mixed moment of $E(XY)$? What is the $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Many thanks here.

Comment: We ask that you include your thoughts and progress in every post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also, must you compute $E[XY]$ (directly)? I am assuming you are asking because you want the covariance. If you don't have to then, there are better ways to compute the covariance.

Comment: What is the better way to compute the cov? Help!

Comment: Graham's answer. In general there are many ways to compute $E[XY]$ indirectly. If you find yourself trying to compute it using the definition, then you are probably doing too much work (unless of course if it a strange pdf problem).

Answer (score 3):

Yes.   If $X$ is the count of successes in $N$ Bernoulli trials, then $N-X$ is the count of the failures.   This will have a distribution of: $\mathcal{Bin}(N, 1-p)$.

Since $Y=N-X$ then the Linearity of Expectation will tell you:

> $$\mathsf E(XY)=N~\mathsf E(X)-\mathsf E(X^2)$$

You can evaluate this knowing that $X$ is Binomially distributed.

Similarly Bilinearity of Covariance says:

> $$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)= \mathsf {Cov}(X,N)-\mathsf {Cov}(X,X)$$